# Laravel orderBy with column value

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

This is the code that I currently have:

```
$programmefundings = Programmefunding::where('status', '!=', 'draft')->orderByRaw("FIELD(status , 'open', 'announced', 'delayed', 'closed') ASC")->orderBy('date_start', 'desc')->get();
```

So it gets all of my programmefundings except the ones with the status **'draft'**, reorders them from **'open'** to **'closed'** and arranges them by **'date_start'**.

I need to reorder the programmefundings which have the status 'announced' by another column **'announcement_date'** in **'asc'** order without disturbing the **'open'** to **'closed'** structure it currently has and without effecting any other programmefindings which do not have the status value **'announced'**.

Is this possible and does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this with an `IF` statement.

```
$programmefundings = Programmefunding::where('status', '!=', 'draft')
    ->orderByRaw("FIELD(status , 'open', 'announced', 'delayed', 'closed') ASC")
    ->orderByRaw("IF(status = 'announced', accouncement_date, date_start) DESC")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking to do is something like this.  It will orderby all items with a status of announced first by announcement date, then it will sort everything else by date_start.

```
$programmefundings = Programmefunding::where('status', '!=', 'draft')
    ->orderByRaw("case when status = 'announced' then announcement_date end asc")
    ->orderBy('date_start', 'desc')->get();
```