# Cant fetch data in order in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

My goal is, A slider will show 2 different types of data : data for page Certified-Ethical-Hacker and data for all other pages. Data for page Certified-Ethical-Hacker will be displayed first, then data for all other pages will come.

The design of our existing table is :

[image]

orderBy() should be based on column "page_slug" . Our codes so far : from  controller

```
public function microsoft_azure_fundamental() {
    
    $bootcamps=DB::table('bootcamps')->select('bootcamps.*','course_languages.course_title')- 
      >leftJoin('course_languages', function($join) {
        $join->on('course_languages.id', '=', 'bootcamps.course_id');
    })->where('bootcamps.page_slug','Certified-Ethical-Hacker')->where('bootcamps.status',1)- 
       >orderBy('event_start',DESC)->get();
    return view('user.pages.cloud_training_microsoft_azure_fundamental', 
     compact('topbarDatas', 'courseOverviews','syllabi','faqs', 'footerIcons',' 
     footerData','bootcamps'));
}
```

Comment: `orderBy('event_start','DESC')->get();` use like this

Comment: It will get data orderBy date, but we need FIRST orderBy "page_slug" = "Certified-Ethical-Hacker", THEN orderBy "page_slug" = other page slugs

Comment: You may try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624879/laravel-orderby-with-column-value

Comment: Please describe better your issue. What is actually your question? How can you define orderBy or how to split it in 2 pages?